Send me a copy, and oblige

Send me a copy, and oblige.

Who is the person who obliges? The person who send the copy or the person who receives the copy?

"Please oblige me by sending a copy" would be more natural.

It is very old fashioned as British business English, sounds like Indian office English, like 'kindly do the needful and oblige' - not seen in British use for 100 years.

In UK or US English "oblige" is more likely to relate to forcing or requiring someone to do something (an "obligation"), except in phrases like "I'm happy to oblige" (note the first-person). There's something demeaning or patronizing about asking someone to "oblige me". Of course, India could be entirely different.

Like much Indian business and bureaucratic language, the apparently trailing 'and oblige' is a relic of archaic English-language business letter etiquette from perhaps 1700 to 1920. Readers may be familiar with such expressions, used about months, as ult (from Latin ultimo, last month) and inst (the current month) e.g. the 17 ult (the 17th of last month). Business letters were begun and ended with very flowery language in which the sender was humbled and the recipient flattered, for example a purchase order would have been called an 'esteemed favour'.
If the letter ended with a request, then very often the words 'and oblige' would be followed by the name of the sender, sometimes on a separate line, which was perhaps preceded by something like 'your most humble and obedient servant':

LONDON, 3rd July, 1842
Mr James Smith
22 High Street
Reading
Berkshire
My dear Sir
I thank you for your most esteemed favour of the 28th ult., in which
you request me to supply 10 gross of wooden rocking-horses.
Please advise me of the address to which they should be sent,
And oblige
Your most humble servant,
Michael Harvey

I have noticed that later practice (and in America) was to have all the last material ('and oblige your most humble servant') on one line above the writer's name.

Oblige takes the third sense 3 of Collins Dictionary:

verb intransitive to do a favor or service

The speaker is asking the other person to send him or her a copy and do a favour or service.
